# Aligning an instance using an angle between two edges with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have some geometry edges and at each vertex that's linked to two edges I want an instance of an object and I want these instances to be oriented between the edges. On the left is an example of the desired result and on the right is where I'm stuck:

[image]

In theory I should get two adjusting vectors for each point, find their dot product and then arccos the result. In practice I guess something in my tree isn't doing that.

My GN tree:

[image]

and my scene:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your edge-only mesh to a poly-curve, the vertices have an order forced on them, and the  X orientation at the control-points bisects the angle between the edges, so that bit is done for you.

What's left is to determine whether the acute angle between the edge-directions entering and leaving each control-point is clockwise or anticlockwise, so we know which instances to flip.

This can be found by detecting  whether the cross-product of those vectors is 'up' or 'down' with respect to a given normal, by the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule). Here the given normal is (0,0,1):

[image]

The group also uses the *Offset Point in Curve*'s  'Is Valid' output to filter out end-points. It can be used thus:

[image]

.. to give your oriented instances:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ooooh I didn't think of that, using a curve and Rotation attribute. Awesome — thank you for the solution and the file !